# Solving Vector Recurrence Involving Normalized Vectors

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am dealing with the following recurrent form:
\begin{equation}
\forall t \geq 1 \,;\, \boldsymbol{x}_t = \boldsymbol{x}_{t-1} - \epsilon \frac{\boldsymbol{a} \circ \boldsymbol{x}_{t-1}}{\| \boldsymbol{a} \circ \boldsymbol{x}_{t-1}\|}
\end{equation}
Here $\epsilon>0$ and both $\boldsymbol{x}_t$ (for all $t$) and $\boldsymbol{a}$ are vectors, respectively in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ (latter meaning strictly positive components), and $\circ$ shows the element-wise product (hence the result will be again a vector).
Given a base solution $\boldsymbol{x}_0$, is it possible to solve this recurrent equation and find a closed form for $\boldsymbol{x}_t$?

Thanks,

Golabi

Comment: Out of curiosity: is this Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: No! It arose in least squares setting :)